# A python script that returns expected returns, covariance and volatility of 2 assets

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, financial, quantitative-finance

Inspired by my excel finance class test, I want to use Python as a tool to solve this problem. [image: test]

I want to learn how to calculate for expected returns, co variance and volatility of assets, especially with the inclusion of probability of events.

```
Expected return (ERi) =  Prob(i) * Returns(i)
```

Here is my current WIP code plan in an attempt to solve this problem:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

p = np.array([0.25, 0.5, 0.25])
r1 = np.array([0.05, 0.075, 0.1])
r2 = np.array([0.2, 0.15, 0.1])

er1 = <<need help returning a single float as expected return of asset 1>>
er2 = <<need help returning a single float as expected return of asset 2>>

portfolio = pd.DataFrame([er1, er2])

weights = np.array([0.5, 0.5])
returns_portfolio = np.dot(weights, portfolio)

cov_matrix = <<need help returning the covariance matrix for the assests>>

portfolio_volatility = <<need help returning the std of returns of the two assets>>
```

I have stored the probabilities of events and returns of each asset is said events as numpy arrays. The confusion for me in python is the inclusion of the probabilities and associating returns.

Just like the formula states, I want to return a sum of the `probability of event(i)* return on event(i) for each separate asset`

With the values of the expected returns for each asset, I plan on creating a returns array to store these values:

```
returns = pd.DataFrame([er1, er2])
```

I hope to use `np.dot(weights, portfolio)` to get the returns of a portfolio made equally weighted of the two assets.

I also need direction with how to implement the `.cov` method and `.std` method to get the co-variance matrix and volatility of the portfolio.

Any tips also warmly welcomed.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @JoshuaStokes basically get the expected returns of each asset before using those inputs to get the portfolio returns and risk

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you show us some code for er1?

Comment: @P.Camilleri I can't show the exact code in python but in excel basically multiply the probability of each event by the return in said event and summed them up as the ER for the asset

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems extremely simple using only array multiplication and `numpy` built in functions such as `dot`, `var` or `std`:

```
er1 = (p * r1).sum()
```

Why would portfolio or returns be a `DataFrame` and not a `np.array`? Just use `np.array([er1, er2])`

Then use `np.std(returns)` or `returns.std()`

Comment: I am still very new at Python so I'm still coming to terms with the data structures of pandas and numpy. The formulae makes so much sense. I can read it as what I wanted in the first place. Thank you so much

Comment: the function plus the .sum() method is exactly I was struggling to cook up in Python. Translating my excel knowledge is the struggle

Comment: @Mysterio I suggest you follow a basic numpy tutorial

Comment: I'm reading books and taking a couple of python courses on udemy. Started a month ago so all over the place with the scattered (limited) python knowledge. Any tips?

Comment: I found the basic doc useful when I started: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/user/quickstart.html

Comment: To get the covariance between r1 and r2, the .cov method on the returns should do the trick?